# Flasing cursor in search engine box is split in two and webpage graphics appear torn

Tags: drivers, graphics, firefox

The flashing cursor in the search box in the search engine has split in two. And the graphics on a webpage sometimes look like torn wallpaper. It also happens sometimes when I highlight text in a webpage. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening as I’ve never experienced this before. This only happens in Firefox. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. It does not happen in Linux Mint 20.2. Only in Ubuntu. It does not seem to be having any adverse effect on system capabilities but it is very annoying.

Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G2020 @ 2.90GHz × 2
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)
Gnome Version: 3.36.8

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do to correct it, please. I would also be very grateful if any technical advice is done by numbers as I have no experience of scripting and have only used the Command Line for installing/removing software. I have been using Ubuntu for 11 years but have only engaged with it previously via the GUI.

Comment: What is "the search engine"? Where does it comefrom? Also, what is "technical advice done by numbers"? Lastly, consider a lighter alternative like Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Mate, you hardware is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the Kernel from 5.11 to 5.14 and the problems I was experiencing have disappeared. I have been testing the Kernel for nearly three weeks with no adverse effects.

What is the search engine? Answer: all of them. Technical advice done by numbers? Answer: i.e. step1, step2, step3, etc.